# Issue with passing parameters in socket.emit()

Tags: javascript, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

```js
            document.querySelector('#sendmessage').onclick = () => {
                const channel = "sports";
                const name = document.querySelector('#displayname').data("displayname");
                const msg = document.querySelector('[name="message"]').value;
                const time = timeStamp();
                //message(n,d,t);
                socket.emit('updatemessage', {'channel':channel, 'name':name, 'msg':msg, 'time':time});
            }
```

I'm having issue with passing these four parameters (channel, name, msg, time) in socket.emit() part. I need to pass them over to store the message details over flask server. Am I allowed to pass more than one parameters? If not, how do I deal with this?

Edit:
Flask snippet

```py
@socketio.on('updatemessage')
def updatemessage(data):
    print("initialised")
    channel = data["channel"]
    name = data["name"]
    channels[channel][name][0] = data["msg"]
    channels[channel][name][1] = data["time"]
    print(f" this is the update channel info : {channels}")
    m = channels[channel]
    print(f"m is :  {m}")
    emit('message loader', m, broadcast=True)
```

Actually I'm trying to store the message data in global variable in flask server

Comment: You can send it any number of arguments after the event name.



Ref: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack

Comment: @RajaSimon when I run the flask server, I've added print statements for debugging, which aren't displayed on terminal, so I figured that socket.emit() is not reaching to the named event 'updatemessage' in flask server.

Comment: Can you show your server code as well? Did you click the sendmessage after the flask server run?

Comment: @RajaSimon I've edited the description. And yes, after starting the flask server, I clicked the sendmessage button.

Comment: hey I checked it out and found out there was some problem with this line `const name = document.querySelector('#displayname').data("displayname");`  and now it's working perfectly. I was in belief that it must have been `socket.emit()` part that's creating the problem @RajaSimon

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question!

I checked found out there was some problem with this line 
`const name = document.querySelector('#displayname').data("displayname");`

and now it's working perfectly. I was in belief that it must have been `socket.emit()` part that's creating the problem